# How smooth transform between two steps in css animation

Tags: css

there is my code , I want have a transition between two step frames.

I put transition in `div` selector but nothing happend

```
transition: top .3s ease;
animation: animate-top steps(6) 10s infinite;
```

https://codepen.io/Qquanwei/pen/RzBdBb?editors=1100

```html
<section>
  <div>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  transition: top .3s ease;
  animation: animate-top steps(6) 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to{
    top: -120px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the way you are using keyframes here. You need to divide the `top` position (120) by the number of steps you’d like (in this case 7, not 6) and break that down into individual keyframe steps. In this case, each keyframe step is 16.66% of the total transition.

Also, you will need to remove the steps declaration from the keyframes call in the css for `div`, as you are no longer doing it this way.

Change your `div` css to this:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  transition: top 3s ease;
  animation: animate-top 10s infinite;
}
```

Change your `keyframes` css to this:

```
   @keyframes animate-top {
      0% {
        top:0px;
      }
      16.66% {
        top:-20px;
      }
      33.33% {
        top:-40px;
      }
      50% {
        top:-60px;
      }
      66.66% {
        top:-80px;
      }
      83.33%{
        top:-100px;
      }
      100% {
        top:-120px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. i want two steps have a transition, overflow seems not effect this.

Comment: I want smooth transition only in two steps gaps . like scrolling...pause...scrolling...pause...scrolling.

Comment: @quanweili please see my updated answer. I believe this is what you want.